# Array Doesn't Push Elements Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, node.js

I'm creating a simple form that allows user to submit input that is displayed on the page. Each input is added after the other, so if the user enters "1" and clicks submit, then "1" would be displayed on the page. If the user then enters "2", then "2" would be displayed right underneath "1". "1" is NOT removed.

I'm saving the user input into the array and I will iterate over that array to render the user input on the page. The problem I'm running into is that nothing in my array gets saved, so when I try to render the user input onto the page, nothing rendered.

```
    /* This is pseudocode */
    var list = [];

    for each value in list
        add value to page

    addToList = function() {
        var value = document.getElementById("userEntry").value;
        list.push(value);
    }
```

The addToList function is called whenever the user clicks submit. I'm using Node.js and I feel that this doesn't work because the JavaScript file gets refreshed every time I submit and the page reloads, clearing the array.

What should I do if I want my array to save the values of the user inputs.

Comment: `<input type="submit">`  will refresh the page. Try using button.

Comment: My button type was submit, not my input type. Does button type being submit also refresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Lepanto is right. 
`<input type="submit">` will refresh the page and you will lose your state. try this:

`<button onclick="addToList" >submit</button>`

Comment: my input type was text. My button type was submit.

Comment: the submit type is precisely what causes the refresh.

Answer (score 0):

try use JQuery and then "$('#userEntry').val()"
and a the button (/element)

```
$('#button').click(() => { 
    list.push($('#userEntry').val());
})"
```

Answer (score 0):

To persist data, You could save the data in localStorage.

Here is how you could do it.

```
  /* This is pseudocode */
    var list = [];

    for each value in list
        add value to page

    addToList = function() {
        var value = document.getElementById("userEntry").value;
        list.push(value);
    }

   onSubmit = function() {
        //localStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
        localStorage.setItem('myList', JSON.stringify(list));
   }

   getList = function() {
        //localStorage.getItem('key');
        list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myList'));
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have initialised a reference to a Function instance with the name addToList but have never invoked this Function.

Add a console.log inside the addToList Function and you will see that this Function is never called.

Instead you need to declare the Function, and then execute it by calling it with parenthesis: `addToList()`